# Traveling with a company to get work in Australia

Tags: working-visas, australia, working, job-hunting

I'm traveling for my first time, alone, to Australia. I'm combining travel and work. I want to work at a range or with cattle care. I'm looking for people with experience traveling with an agency or company helping out with finding work etc. I have been looking specifically at the website https://www.work-n-travel-australia.com/program/farm-work-schedule/ but don't find any kind of unaffected review or feedback on the program.
Kind regards Jenny

Comment: Welcome to Expats.SE -- but what exactly is your question?

Comment: You'll need a visa to work in Australia (unless you're an Australian). Be sure you get the right one - making a mistake with visas can affect your future travels for years. That web site refers to 'working holiday' in a couple of places, but the Australian [Working Holiday Visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-417/first-working-holiday-417) must be applied for from __outside__ Australia. You should verify that you will get the correct paperwork.